# $|\int_a^b f(x)dx| \leq |\int_a^b |f(x)| dx| $?

Tags: real-analysis

For $a>b$ Does the following hold:

$|\int_a^b f(x)dx| \leq |\int_a^b |f(x)| dx| $ ?

At $"\leq"$ I have used the triangular inequality for integrals:

If $f:I\to \mathbb{R} $ is Riemann integrable over $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $a,b \in I$ with $a < b$, then $|\int_a^b f(x)dx| \leq \int_a^b |f(x)| dx $.

Answer (score 1):

When $a>b$ we define $\int_a^{b}f(x)dx$ as $- \int_b^{a}f(x)dx$. So the inequality is true and it reduces to the case $a<b$.

To be explicit we have $|\int_a^{b} f(x)dx| =|\int_b^{a}f(x)dx| \leq \int_b^{a}|f(x)|dx=|\int_a^{b}|f(x)|dx|$

Comment: Yes, so what I was trying to do is prove that for all $a,b \in I$ the following is true
$\left|\int_{a}^{b} f(x) d x\right| \leq\left|\int_{a}^{b}\right| f(x)|d x| ?$.

So for $a < b$, I could use the inequalities directly. For $a>b$ is used the definition $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) d x a s-\int_{b}^{a} f(x) d x$ so that I could use the tri. inequality to prove $\left|\int_{a}^{b} f(x) d x\right| \leq\left|\int_{a}^{b}\right| f(x)|d x| ?$.

Comment: @Xenusi I have edited my answer. I hope the steps in then proof are clear.